# Fragment's layout being covered up by activity's toolbar/tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-tabs

I have a single activity app with a nav drawer to navigate between a few fragments. The activity also has a toolbar and a tab layout, and I have it so that the tabs stay hidden through visibility-gone until the fragment with a view pager is switched to. The problem is that the contents of the tabbed fragment are hidden underneath the toolbar and the tab display. Any ideas?

Main Activity Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">
        </include>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/TabsDisplay"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"/>
    </FrameLayout>

<!--The drawer stuff is below -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_navDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorSecondary_text"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"/>
```

Toolbar Layout: ( I just had this seperate through different attempts at it, and never merged it back in.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"/>
```

I have a basic layout as an 'intro page' that just displays a textview right now that is put into the container on startup, that is replaced by the other fragments through the nav drawer. One of them has a viewpager, that enables the tablayout to appear, the tabs display and load with text and fragments properly, but they are being covered up by the toolbar/tab bar. I have tried having the tablayout directly into the fragment, but then it never displayed at all, and am having trouble finding the correct way to do this.

Tabbed/Viewpager Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/tabTestVP"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout and give the following attribute to the FrameLayout:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
```

Make sure to add the ID to the toolbar first

Answer (score 0):

U can use a RelativeLayout in place of the first FrameLayout in your hierarchy  and align the Fragment container below the  AppBarLayout. "android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"